# Select multiple fields using jq

Tags: json, object, jq, declarative

I am trying to filter docker-machine's output using the following jq filter.

```
docker-machine inspect default | jq '{ConfigVersion, .Driver.{MachineName, CPU, Memory}, DriverName}'
```

The original json for the first command is here

```
{
    "ConfigVersion": 3,
    "Driver": {
        "IPAddress": "192.168.99.100",
        "MachineName": "default",
        "SSHUser": "docker",
        "SSHPort": 52314,
        "SSHKeyPath": "/Users/apatil/.docker/machine/machines/default/id_rsa",
        "StorePath": "/Users/apatil/.docker/machine",
        "SwarmMaster": false,
        "SwarmHost": "tcp://0.0.0.0:3376",
        "SwarmDiscovery": "",
        "VBoxManager": {},
        "HostInterfaces": {},
        "CPU": 2,
        "Memory": 5120,
        "DiskSize": 20000,
        "NatNicType": "82540EM",
        "Boot2DockerURL": "",
        "Boot2DockerImportVM": "",
        "HostDNSResolver": false,
        "HostOnlyCIDR": "192.168.99.1/24",
        "HostOnlyNicType": "82540EM",
        "HostOnlyPromiscMode": "deny",
        "UIType": "headless",
        "HostOnlyNoDHCP": false,
        "NoShare": false,
        "DNSProxy": true,
        "NoVTXCheck": false,
        "ShareFolder": ""
    },
    "DriverName": "virtualbox",
    "HostOptions": {
        "Driver": "",
        "Memory": 0,
        "Disk": 0,
        "EngineOptions": {
            "ArbitraryFlags": [],
            "Dns": null,
            "GraphDir": "",
            "Env": [],
            "Ipv6": false,
            "InsecureRegistry": [],
            "Labels": [],
            "LogLevel": "",
            "StorageDriver": "",
            "SelinuxEnabled": false,
            "TlsVerify": true,
            "RegistryMirror": [],
            "InstallURL": "https://get.docker.com"
        },
        "SwarmOptions": {
            "IsSwarm": false,
            "Address": "",
            "Discovery": "",
            "Agent": false,
            "Master": false,
            "Host": "tcp://0.0.0.0:3376",
            "Image": "swarm:latest",
            "Strategy": "spread",
            "Heartbeat": 0,
            "Overcommit": 0,
            "ArbitraryFlags": [],
            "ArbitraryJoinFlags": [],
            "Env": null,
            "IsExperimental": false
        },
        "AuthOptions": {
            "CertDir": "/Users/apatil/.docker/machine/certs",
            "CaCertPath": "/Users/apatil/.docker/machine/certs/ca.pem",
            "CaPrivateKeyPath": "/Users/apatil/.docker/machine/certs/ca-key.pem",
            "CaCertRemotePath": "",
            "ServerCertPath": "/Users/apatil/.docker/machine/machines/default/server.pem",
            "ServerKeyPath": "/Users/apatil/.docker/machine/machines/default/server-key.pem",
            "ClientKeyPath": "/Users/apatil/.docker/machine/certs/key.pem",
            "ServerCertRemotePath": "",
            "ServerKeyRemotePath": "",
            "ClientCertPath": "/Users/apatil/.docker/machine/certs/cert.pem",
            "ServerCertSANs": [],
            "StorePath": "/Users/apatil/.docker/machine/machines/default"
        }
    },
    "Name": "default"
}
```

I am getting the following error from jq for the command above

```
$ docker-machine inspect default | jq '{ConfigVersion, .Driver.{MachineName, CPU, Memory}, DriverName}'
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected FIELD (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
{ConfigVersion, .Driver.{MachineName, CPU, Memory}, DriverName}
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
{ConfigVersion, .Driver.{MachineName, CPU, Memory}, DriverName}
jq: 2 compile errors
```

Answer (score 6):

Fixed it using

```
$ docker-machine inspect default |
  jq '{ConfigVersion,
       Driver: (.Driver|{MachineName, CPU, Memory}),
       DriverName}'
{
  "ConfigVersion": 3,
  "Driver": {
    "MachineName": "default",
    "CPU": 2,
    "Memory": 5120
  },
  "DriverName": "virtualbox"
}
```